# Declined flag on classic "list" question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question:

[Forums with lot of hand history analysis by other players](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/910/forums-with-lot-of-hand-history-analysis-by-other-players)

Which starts out with:

> Can you give me some links please to forums with...

is a classic question asking for a "list" of answers, so I flagged it as too broad and the flag was declined.  On SO, this is clearly too broad, and a "list" type question is often cited as an example of the type of question that should be flagged this way.  The [help file](https://poker.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
> avoid asking **subjective questions** where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
>
> your
> answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
> answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

This seems like a classic example of a broad question.  Are the rules here different?

Answer (score 1):

Not all "list" questions are created equal. ;)

Seriously though, this is more of a request for sources. Kind of like a "which book is best?" or a "Where should a beginner start to learn...?" question. Plenty of those on SE sites.

Also, you highlight **"subjective question**" in your help file example but I think you're mistaken in this case. Hand history resource links are completely objective. They're either there, or they're not! If the question was about the quality of the repositories then that might be subjective.

I can also attest to the difficulty of getting quality, non commercial, hand history files. Personally, I would've liked a list of this sort. Also, the types of objective questions that might be asked when manipulating raw data are great for this site, so why not provide the materials for it, then users can come back and ask the questions they need answers to, that relate to the data!

I didn't close it because of these reasons. Its nothing personal of course. If you feel my reasoning is inadequate please comment. I appreciate you asking the question on meta, its a fair point to make.

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for the answer.  I still disagree, however I won't have time to explain why for a few days.  Keep in mind that I'm not saying that it is not a good question, or even a good answer.  Just that I see over and over that these types of questions are not welcome on SE, and even more so the examples that you give in your answer.  "which book is best" is VERY subjective and would probably be closed in less than a minute on SO.  :-)